# The Opposite of Perfect

Tags: word-request, antonyms

I am trying to assign a human readable tag that describes how good an object is. For example grading a student's paper:

```
string quality = grade_paper(string paper);
```

The quality has to be an alphabetical string (specifically not a number).

Before I can proceed, I need a list of qualities I can report. Here's what I have so far:

> very poor, poor, fair, good, excellent, outstanding, perfect

This list seems unbalanced because perfect implies the complete absence of flaws.

Is there a single word that is the opposite of perfect? Perfectly bad just seems like a kludge.

Comment: As a developer, I feel your pain. In a similar case, we used *fubar*. Not sure if it applies to your context, if it's acceptable in the code base nor if it's even relevant as your question was posted 7+ years ago. (And yes, it's an acronym, so technically, one should spell it capitalized but we had the casing style guide enforcing it.)

Answer (score 4):

You could say **Unacceptable** or **Completely Unacceptable**.

BTW, many people might consider **excellent** and **outstanding**  synonyms.

Answer (score 3):

**Atrocious** would seem to fit your needs

> Of a very poor quality; extremely bad or unpleasant

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/atrocious

Or perhaps use what (at least) the UK School system uses, **Ungradable**, or grade U. It literally means no content worth grading.

Comment: I believe it's “Ungraded”, and it can mean at least two things, but I suppose the adjective should follow.